# Selenium WebDriver through authenticated proxy in headless mode alternative (via OpenVPN?)

Tags: vpn, selenium-webdriver

I discovered, that it is not easily possible for me to use proxies with the Selenium WebDriver due to selenium-wire not running in headless mode.

Is it possible to use vpn-packages like OpenVPN to route the outgoing HTTP calls through my given authenticated proxy? The internet is full of tutorials how to set up a Raspberry Pi as a vpn-server. But I struggle to find a tutorial how to simply connect to a known proxy server via ip, port, id, password.

What workflow would you recommend to achieve the proxy connection?

I use a headless Raspbian on a RPi 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: linux questions should be posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions